# Java Spring JPA Pagination Not working if more than one Page

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use jpa Pagination with custom query.

pagination is working if match with 2 cases.

Case 1 :

- if data available less than 10 and request with page number is 0

if not the request not working

and

Case 2:

- if data available more than 10 and request with page number is 1

if not pagination is not working.

i cant figure out the problem. Any help guys?

Thanks in advance.

```
@Repository
public interface SmsLogRepository extends JpaRepository<SmsLog, Long> {

@Query(value = "select * from sms_log s where s.phone_number = (:ph) \n#pageable\n", nativeQuery = true)
Page<SmsLog> findByPhoneNumber(@Param("ph") String phoneNumber, Pageable pageable);

@Query(value = "select * from sms_log s where s.phone_number = (:ph) AND s.message_timestamp between (:fromdate) and (:todate) \n#pageable\n", nativeQuery = true)
Page<SmsLog> findByPhoneNumberAndDate(@Param("ph") String phoneNumber, @Param("fromdate") String fromDate, @Param("todate") String todate, Pageable pageable);

@Query(value = "select * from sms_log s where s.message_timestamp between (:fromdate) and (:todate) \n#pageable\n", nativeQuery = true)
Page<SmsLog> findByDate(@Param("fromdate") String fromDate, @Param("todate") String todate, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Request :

```
PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(page, 10, new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "message_timestamp")));
            return logRepository.findByPhoneNumber(ph, pageRequest);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending some time i found the answer

I missed the count query. After adding the count query pagination worked like charm :)

```
@Repository
public interface SmsLogRepository extends JpaRepository<SmsLog, Long> {

@Query(value = "select * from sms_log s where s.phone_number = (:ph) \n#pageable\n", countQuery = "select count(*) from sms_log s where s.phone_number = (:ph) \n#pageable\n", nativeQuery = true)
Page<SmsLog> findByPhoneNumber(@Param("ph") String phoneNumber, Pageable pageable);

@Query(value = "select * from sms_log s where s.phone_number = (:ph) AND s.message_timestamp between (:fromdate) and (:todate) \n#pageable\n",countQuery = "select count(*) from sms_log s where s.phone_number = (:ph) AND s.message_timestamp between (:fromdate) and (:todate) \n#pageable\n", nativeQuery = true)
Page<SmsLog> findByPhoneNumberAndDate(@Param("ph") String phoneNumber, @Param("fromdate") String fromDate, @Param("todate") String todate, Pageable pageable);

@Query(value = "select * from sms_log s where s.message_timestamp between (:fromdate) and (:todate) \n#pageable\n",countQuery = "select count(*) from sms_log s where s.message_timestamp between (:fromdate) and (:todate) \n#pageable\n", nativeQuery = true)
Page<SmsLog> findByDate(@Param("fromdate") String fromDate, @Param("todate") String todate, Pageable pageable);
}
```