# Spring Data Native query pagination not working

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data, native-sql

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.2.RELEASE with Spring Data JPA. I am trying to do implement pagination with native query in MySql, my code is :

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true, value = "SELECT DISTINCT ud.latitude,ud.longitude,u.user_id userId FROM users u \n" +
            "INNER JOIN user_devices ud ON u.id = ud.user_id\n" +
            "WHERE ud.access_token IS NOT NULL AND ud.user_id <> 1\n" +
            "ORDER BY calculateDistanceByLatLong(:userLat, :userLong, ud.latitude, ud.longitude) ASC \n#pageable\n",
            countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) FROM users u \n" +
                    "INNER JOIN user_devices ud ON u.id = ud.user_id\n" +
            "WHERE ud.access_token IS NOT NULL AND ud.user_id <> 1 \n#pageable\n")
    public Page<LocationProjection> listNearByUsers(@Param("userLat")String userLatitude,@Param("userLong") String userLongitude, Pageable pageable) throws Exception;
```

I got the reference from [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49625873/java-spring-jpa-pagination-not-working-if-more-than-one-page)

And also reviewed [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination)

But it's not adding any pagination code.
When I try to use :

```
userDao.listNearByUsers(userDeviceEntity.getLatitude(),userDeviceEntity.getLongitude(), PageRequest.of(pageNo, maxResults))
```

And for example set pageNo=0 and maxResults =1,all the results are displayed. So no pagination is being implemented.
I printed the fired query, it is :

```
SELECT
DISTINCT ud.latitude,
ud.longitude,
u.user_id userId 
FROM
users u  
INNER JOIN
user_devices ud 
ON u.id = ud.user_id 
WHERE
ud.access_token IS NOT NULL 
AND ud.user_id <> 1 
ORDER BY
calculateDistanceByLatLong(?,
?,
ud.latitude,
ud.longitude) ASC  #pageable
```

And the count query as :

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) 
FROM
users u  
INNER JOIN
user_devices ud 
ON u.id = ud.user_id 
WHERE
ud.access_token IS NOT NULL 
AND ud.user_id <> 1  #pageable
```

I thought Spring Data would add "LIMIT 0,1" in the main query but it's not working. The DAO interface is :

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Integer>{}
```

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: you are using native query but there is no rownum in your query which will apply pagination. Use JPQL and countQuery for this

Comment: @MountainKing I followed the reference links that I have mentioned. There was no such thing. Can you elaborate more ?

Comment: Any news on this? I'm also stuck with the same problem!

Answer (score 11):

After going over several Q/A here, and none working properly (for my setup, at least). After reading this [bit](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_native_queries) at Spring official documentation, I've managed to get it working by simply removing the "pageable" bit from my query.

I'm working with spring-boot version 2.0.1.RELEASE.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
    countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM USERS WHERE LASTNAME = ?1",
    nativeQuery = true)
  Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! My Spring is 2.7.4 and It worked very well!